# How to find out which user executed an SQL statement?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following SQL query ran and reflected in TOP SQL report, am i able to find out the user who executed the SQL from Oracle?

```
SELECT MIN(seq_id) 
  FROM my_log 
 WHERE seq_id >= 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Oracle 10g:

```
SELECT a.username,
       b.sql_text,
       a.status
FROM   v$session a
       INNER JOIN v$sqlarea b
         ON a.sql_id = b.sql_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the SQL_ID of this statement, then look in the [active session history](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_3125.htm).

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure, but have you looked in select * from V$SQL?

Answer (score 0):

```
select USER_ID from V$ACTIVE_SESSION_HISTORY where SQL_ID = 'abpr2y86dr5hv';

select USER_ID,SQL_ID,SQL_PLAN_HASH_VALUE,SQL_FULL_PLAN_HASH_VALUE,SQL_ADAPTIVE_PLAN_RESOLVED  from DBA_HIST_ACTIVE_SESS_HISTORY where SQL_ID = 'abpr2y86dr5hv';

select USER_ID,USERNAME from DBA_USERS where USER_ID = '265';
```